# Google maps with KML in C# WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps

I would like to create a Windows Form that contains a C# WebBrowser that shows a Google Map with KML. The problem is that, after I run my code nothing is displayed on the WebBrowser. I need this for my project.

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser123.DocumentText =
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
"<html>" +
  "<head>" +
    "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\">" +
    "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">" +
    "<title>KML Layers</title>" +
    "<style>" +
                /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
                 * element that contains the map. */
      "#map {" +
       " height: 100%;" +
      "}" +
                /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      "html, body {" +
        "height: 100%;" +
        "margin: 0;" +
        "padding: 0;" +
     " }" +
    "</style>" +
  "</head>" +
  "<body>" +
   " <div id=\"map\"></div>" +
    "<script>" +

      "function initMap() {" +
       " var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {" +
         " zoom: 11," +
          "center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}" +
       " });" +

       " var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({" +
        "  url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml'," +
       "   map: map" +
       " });" +
     " }" +
    "</script>" +
    "<script async defer" +
    "src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAsLmzxet8OI2SHDZ78c3MJdTP1ODoFjZg&callback=initMap\">" +
    "</script>" +
  "</body>" +
"</html>";
    //        webBrowser.DocumentText =
    //"<html><body>Please enter your name:<br/>" +
    //"<input type='text' name='userName'/><br/>" +
    //"<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>continue</a>" +
    //"</body></html>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted my HTML code with http://www.buildmystring.com/ and now everything works fine. Here is my working code if somebody needs it:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


           label1.Text = "Width:" + webBrowser123.Width + " Height: " + webBrowser123.Height;
             // BuildMyString.com generated code. Please enjoy your string responsibly.

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<!DOCTYPE html>");
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.Append("  <head>");
sb.Append("    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale=1.0\">");
sb.Append(" <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\">");
sb.Append("    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">");
sb.Append("    <title>KML Layers</title>");
sb.Append("    <style>");
sb.Append("      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div");
sb.Append("       * element that contains the map. */");
sb.Append("      #map {");
sb.Append("        height: 100%;");
sb.Append("      }");
sb.Append("      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */");
sb.Append("      html, body {");
sb.Append("        height: 100%;");
sb.Append("        margin: 0;");
sb.Append("        padding: 0;");
sb.Append("      }");
sb.Append("    </style>");
sb.Append("  </head>");
sb.Append("  <body>");
sb.Append("    <div id=\"map\"></div>");
sb.Append("    <script>");
sb.Append("");
sb.Append("      function initMap() {");
sb.Append("        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {");
sb.Append("          zoom: 11,");
sb.Append("          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}");
sb.Append("        });");
sb.Append("");
sb.Append("        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({");
sb.Append("          url: 'https://new.enfield.gov.uk/Cemeteries.kml',");
sb.Append("          map: map");
sb.Append("        });");
sb.Append("      }");
sb.Append("    </script>");
sb.Append("    <script async defer");
sb.Append("    src=\"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKEY&callback=initMap&v=3.22\">");
sb.Append("    </script>");
sb.Append("  </body>");
sb.Append("</html>");



webBrowser123.DocumentText = sb.ToString();


        }
```